# undo sorting of nsarray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsarray

Here is a example of what I want to do with NSArray contains NSNumber.

1. This is the NSArray "score" I want to edit.
   score[0]=30,
   score[1]=10,
   score[2]=20
   score[3]=0
2. Sort the Array in ascending-order
   score[0]=30   //[0]This number shows the index before sorting the array
   score[1]=20   //[2]
   score[2]=10   //[1]
   score[3]=0    //[3]
3. Edit the Array(In this case,4th gives 1st 10 points,and 3rd gives 2nd 5points)
   score[0]=40   //[0]
   score[1]=25   //[2]
   score[2]=5   //[1]
   score[3]=-10    //[3]
4. And sort the array back they were.
   score[0]=40
   score[1]=5
   score[2]=25
   score[3]=-10

   I have a problem with no.4 method in the list.Can someone give me some idea with this?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming that final value of `-5` for `score[3]` was a typo since it's clearly supposed to be `-10`. Please confirm that my changes are correct or let me know if I was wrong. As my wife will attest (far too frequently for my liking), that happens occasionally :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually *need* to swap the values themselves, you can set up an extra level of indirection and use that.

Before the sort, you have the indexes initialised to point to the corresponding scores:

```
index[0] = 0      score[0] = 30
index[1] = 1      score[1] = 10
index[2] = 2      score[2] = 20
index[3] = 3      score[3] =  0
```

When you sort, you actually sort the *indexes* based on the scores they point to rather than the scores themselves. So, instead of the following comparison in your sort:

```
if score[i] > score[i+1] then swap score[i], score[i+1]
```

you instead use:

```
if score[index[i]] > score[index[i+1]] then swap index[i], index[i+1]
```

Following the sort, you then have:

```
index[0] = 0      score[0] = 30
index[1] = 2      score[1] = 10   \ These two indexes have been swapped
index[2] = 1      score[2] = 20   /   but NOT the scores.
index[3] = 3      score[3] =  0
```

Then, to move points, you use the indirect indexes rather than the direct values:

```
score[index[0]] += 10; score[index[3]] -= 10;
score[index[1]] +=  5; score[index[2]] -=  5;
```

Then you throw away the indexes altogether, the original array doesn't need restoration to its original order, simply because its order was never *changed.*

Comment: Yeah, I like it. I often find that the fastest way to do something is to _not_ do it :-)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me this way.It's pretty easy to understand.And thanks for correcting typo for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make an additional array initialized as such:

```
index[0] = 0
index[1] = 1
index[2] = 2
:
```

And every time your sorting algorithm swaps two indices in `score`, you also swap the same indices in `index`.

In case your sorting algorithm is built-in, so that you have no control over it, you will have to replace each score with a tuple (an object, a two-element array, whichever is easier in objective-c), where on element is the score, and the other element is its original index. When you sort, you would pass a custom comparator to the sorting function, so that only the score is used for comparison. That would sort your score-index tuples, so that you can use the index to restore them to original order.

Answer (score 0):

[Code will be typed in, check it!]

I assume your `score` array is actually mutable as you intend to alter it:

```
NSMutableArray *score = ...;
```

Create another array the same size and initialized to 0..n:

```
NSMutableArray *indices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[score count]];
// add the numbers 0..[score count] to indices
```

Now sort the `indices` array using a custom comparator which looks up the `score` array:

```
[indices sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(NSNumber *a, NSNumber *b)
 {
    return [((NSNumber *)[[score objectAtIndex:[a integerValue]])
            compare:[[score objectAtIndex:[b integerValue]]
           ];
 }
]
```

Now you can modify your original array via the indices array, e.g. to modify the "4th" element after the source:

```
[score replaceObjectAtIndex:[[indices objectAtIndex:3] integerValue] withObject:...];
```

Now you don't need to "unsort" `score` at all, your step 4 is "do nothing".